# Get the value of one column which interlinks with two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the following when I find the stop name I want to find the 'route' (and the 'direction' if it possible ) from the `routes` table  based on the `arrivaltime` and `weekday` in the `arrivaltimes` table?

**Route table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS routes (
route_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
direction VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
route INT(11) NOT NULL )
```

**Stop table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stops
stop_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
name varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
lat double(10,6) NOT NULL, 
longi double(10,6)NOT NULL)
```

**arrivaltimes table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS arrivaltimes(
    arrivaltimes_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     weekday VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    route INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    arrivaltime time NOT NULL,
    stop_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_stop_id(stop_id) REFERENCES stops(stop_id), 
    route_id INT, FOREIGN KEY fk_route_id(route_id) REFERENCES routes(route_id) )
```

**my query**

```
SELECT route FROM arrivaltimes INNER JOIN stops
 ON arrivaltimes.stop_id = stops.stop_id
and arrivaltimes.route_id = routes.route_id
WHERE weekday = 'sat'
and time_format(arrivaltime,'%H:%i') = time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
 and name LIKE 'Aldgate'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` without any wildcard characters? If you want an exact match, use `name = 'Aldgate'`

Comment: You have `routes.route_id` in your query, but you haven't joined with the `routes` table.

Comment: What's the difference between `route` and `route_id`?

Comment: What does it mean  **stop_id**  in your stop table ?

Comment: @Barmar: how can I join two tables? route is the `route ` number of the various buses. I thought I need that as help to find the directiont later.

Comment: @N.Molderf: stop_id the primary key of the stop table I dont know what do you exactly mean?

Comment: you should re-view your DB design

Comment: @N.Molderf but I am getting result with the answer of `Barmar`?

Comment: look at Where Clause there are a lot of function and your indexes dont work at for thsi query thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join all 3 tables

```
SELECT r.route
FROM routes AS r
JOIN arrivaltimes AS a ON a.route_id = r.route_id
JOIN stops as s on s.stop_id = a.stop_id
WHERE a.weekday = 'sat'
AND time_format(a.arrivaltime,'%H:%i') = time_format(curtime() ,'%H:%i')
AND s.name = 'Aldgate'
```